# How to handle OAuth2 refreshToken with RestKit 0.20

Tags: oauth-2.0, restkit-0.20

I know for method

```
-[[RKObjectManager sharedManager].HTTPClient setAuthorizationHeaderWithToken:]
```

and I suppose that this method accepts accessToken. How to handle OAuth2 refreshToken?

Comment: So you're already handling the OAuth login and getting the token, you then just need to set the token? And the token is sent as a header in each request?

Comment: Yes, that's right. I'm also trying to set AFOAuth2Client (extension on AFHTTPClient) to handle access and refresh tokens, but RKObjectManager returns false response. I'll add code example

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok, I resolve my problem. 
First of all, you have to download AFOAuth2Client from http://goo.gl/zdTdlJ

This is AFHTTPClient extension witch handles OAuth2 authentication and here's snippet how to initialize it and set it into RestKit as HTTPClient.

```
AFOAuthCredential* credential = [AFOAuthCredential credentialWithOAuthToken:accessToken tokenType:kAFOAuthCodeGrantType];
[credential setRefreshToken:refreshToken expiration:expirationDate];
AFOAuth2Client* oAuth2Client = [AFOAuth2Client clientWithBaseURL:[NSURL URLWithString:baseUrl]
                                                                clientID:clientID
                                                                  secret:secret];
[oAuth2Client setAuthorizationHeaderWithToken:accessToken];

// This line is for environment where you don't have valid certificate.
// For example for development environment
[oAuth2Client setAllowsInvalidSSLCertificate:YES];

[[RKObjectManager sharedManager] setHTTPClient:oAuth2Client];
[[RKObjectManager sharedManager] getObjectsAtPath:path parameters:nil 
     success:^(
       RKObjectRequestOperation* operation, RKMappingResult* mappingResult) {
           // Handle success response
     } failure:^(RKObjectRequestOperation* operation, NSError* error) {
          // Handle failure response
}];
```